# Show that the set of continuous functions on $[0, 2\pi]$ follows the dot product associative property

Tags: vector-spaces, definite-integrals

$$f \cdot g = \int_0^{2\pi} f(t)g(t) \, dt$$

Prove that 
$$f \cdot (g \cdot h) = (f \cdot g) \cdot h$$

I'm most just confused as to how to deal with the $\int_0^{2\pi} g(t)h(t) \, dt$

I don't know any formulas or properties for this so I'm just a little stuck

Comment: I don't blame you for being stuck! These products don't actually work as I am sure someone will explain in a moment. What does work is something like $f\cdot (g+h)=f\cdot g+f\cdot h$.

Comment: @jp-McCarthy Was probably a typo then! This makes so much more sense so thank you for pointing it out. You have saved my next 3 hours!